# winform language localization sample for

Tags: winforms, localization

I've the following code to convert the controls in static mode i.e by writing the translated string(french,german etc) and saving the resource file and calling it back. How ever if I need to translate dynamically(including the user-inputs), say like how google translator works. I need to implement the same in offline mode. Is there any possibility to access google like translators, which instantly/dynamically translates to the selected language, but offline? Or please suggest me any preferred method.

```
foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
    {
        ComponentResourceManager resources = new ComponentResourceManager(typeof(MainForm));
        resources.ApplyResources(c, c.Name, new CultureInfo(lang));
    }
```

--
Regards,
Manohar.

Answer (score 0):

I don`t know if it helps you, but here is what I did. It's written in managed c++ /clr you can easyly translat it to c#. 
I wrote a little helper calss to manage the translation process

(You can change the language during runtime with this! It will instantly translate the whole form.)

```
ref class LanguageSwitcher
{
public:
   /// <summary>
   /// Change language at runtime in the specified form
   /// </summary>
   [System::Runtime::CompilerServices::Extension]
   static void SetLanguage( Form ^form, CultureInfo ^lang )
   {
      //Set the language in the application
      System::Threading::Thread::CurrentThread->CurrentUICulture = lang;

      ComponentResourceManager ^resources = gcnew ComponentResourceManager( form->GetType() );

      ApplyResourceToControl( resources, form->MainMenuStrip, lang );
      ApplyResourceToControl( resources, form, lang );

      form->Text = resources->GetString( "$this.Text", lang );
   }
private:
   static void ApplyResourceToControl( ComponentResourceManager ^resources, Control ^control, CultureInfo ^lang )
   {
      for each( Control ^c in control->Controls )
      {
         ApplyResourceToControl( resources, c, lang );
         String ^text = resources->GetString( c->Name + ".Text", lang );
         if( text != nullptr )
            c->Text = text;
      }
   }

   static void ApplyResourceToControl( ComponentResourceManager ^resources, MenuStrip ^menu, CultureInfo ^lang )
   {
      if(menu != nullptr)
         for each( ToolStripItem ^m in menu->Items )
         {
            String ^text = resources->GetString( m->Name + ".Text", lang );
            if( text != nullptr )
               m->Text = text;
         }
    }
};
```

This is how it is used:

```
System::Globalization::CultureInfo^ lang = cli::safe_cast<System::Globalization::CultureInfo^ >(langCombo->SelectedItem);
LanguageSwitcher::SetLanguage(this,lang);
```

Hope this helps!